# Why does my TMP's face color update only at 50% and 150%?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ello,
I am currently working on a mechanic for a local multiplayer roguelike where the closer the players are to each other the more damage they do. So far I've gotten multipliers to work and change damage statistics but I cant get my % text to update as the total multiplier does. In its current state, the text mesh pros face color updates at only 50% and 150% when it should do it every frame. Any ideas as to why is this is or any potential fixes?

Thanks

**Statistics** (For totalMultiplier)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Stats : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject midpoint;
    public float baseDamage;
    [SerializeField] private float damage;
    [SerializeField] private float multiplier = 1;
    public float totalMultiplier;
    private float distMulti;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        multiplier = 1;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //actual multiplier
        damage = (baseDamage * multiplier) / (midpoint.GetComponent<Midpoint>().distance * 0.5f);
        if (damage >= (baseDamage * multiplier * 2))
        {
            damage = (baseDamage * multiplier * 2);
        }
        //Keep track of multiplier
        totalMultiplier = damage / baseDamage;
    }
}
```

**Text Tracker / Color Changer** (Edits the TMPs shader with setting faceColor)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class TextTracker : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    private TextMeshPro text;
    private Color redAmount = Color.red;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        text = GetComponent<TextMeshPro>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        text.SetText(System.Math.Round((player.GetComponent<Stats>().totalMultiplier)* 100, 0).ToString() + "%");
        transform.position = new Vector2(player.transform.position.x, player.transform.position.y + 1);
        Shader color = text.material.shader;

        text.faceColor = new Color(1f, 1f - (float)System.Math.Round(player.GetComponent<Stats>().totalMultiplier) / 2, 1f - (float)System.Math.Round(player.GetComponent<Stats>().totalMultiplier) / 2, 1f);

    }
}
```

Comment: Boys Im a little slow. Just realised that the problem was my rounding. Just increasing the number of decimals helps it. it was getting stuck at 0.5 and 1. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah my problem was the Math.Round function. It was set to 0 so it would only round to whole numbers. Increasing it fixed it all up.